# ROR Compilar sass en producción

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, scss

Alguien me puede ayudar por favor. Les comento que tengo un gran problema y no se como solucionarlo, busque en todos lados y no encontre nada bueno.

Lo que pasa es que tengo mi archivo `application.scss.erb` al cual le paso unos colores desde la BD

```
$blue-md: #<%= colors.primary_color %>;
```

todo bien hasta el momento, pero el usuario tiene una vista donde puede actualizar esos valores y me gustaría saber como cambiar el estilo de la pagina en tiempo real, osea recompilar los archivos de estilo.

Comment: Si quieres que cada vez que seleccione un color se guarde, entonces podrías hacerlo con AJAX y luego JS/jQuery; aunque yo recomendaría únicamente utilizar JS/jQuery para que el usuario pruebe (i.e. cambie varias veces y vea el resultado) y ya que decida el color, entonces de clic en guardar y se haga el update en la BD.

Comment: El color lo guardo correctamente, el problema es que no se ven reflejados los cambios, hasta que reinicie el servidor. la idea es que el usuario al momento de presionar sobre el boton actualizar, se vean todos los cambios inmediatamente.

Comment: Desconozco de algún método/clase que Rails ofrezca para ese efecto, pero podrías generar la hoja de estilo dinámicamente; [este artículo](http://matteodepalo.github.io/blog/2013/01/31/how-to-create-custom-stylesheets-dynamically-with-rails-and-sass/) (en inglés) puede ayudarte.

Comment: Creo que estás abordando el problema desde la perspectiva incorrecta. No creo que sea la mejor solución recompilar tu css por cada valor distinto que traigas desde la BD. Con rails 5 el proceso de compilación de assets se ha delegado a webpack en vez de usar sprockets, lo cual se corre al momento de deployar en producción, así que dudo que funcione del todo la solución de gerry. Creo que deberías manipular el css a través de javascript o, en su defecto, agregar los estilos a cambiar dentro de tu plantilla `.html.erb`, los cuales si son evaluados en cada desplegue por pantalla.

Comment: @AlterLagos entiendo completamente lo que me dices, pero necesito editar la variable sass, para asi poder remplazar todas las clases que la utilizan esa variable.